# Mantener efecto hover al seleccionarlo

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Tengo un problema para mantener el efecto `hover`, busco al hacer clic que la imagen mantenga el efecto hover, y si selecciono la otra imagen se se quite el efecto de la primera imagen, y la segunda imagen mantenga su efecto hover. Que funcione como un input tipo radio, en este caso una imagen se mantendrá seleccionada.

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        .images1
{
 width: 80px;
 height: 80px;
 background-image: url('icono/educacionp.png');
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.images1:hover
{
 background-image: url('icono/educacion.png');
 cursor: pointer;
}
.clasehover
{
background-image: url('icono/educacion.png');
}
.images2
{
 width: 80px;
 height: 80px;
 background-image: url('icono/Emprendimientop.png');
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.images2:hover
{
  background-image: url('icono/Emprendimiento.png'); 
}
.clasehover2
{
  background-image: url('icono/Emprendimiento.png'); 
}
.container{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content:center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.container p{
  margin-top:60px;
  font-size: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.imgicon{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  cursor: pointer;
   margin: 30px;
}
.textlarge{
  display: flex;
}
.imgicon input{
  margin-top: 55px;
  margin-left: -30px;
}

    </style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="imgicon images1">
        <label class="textlarge icono-educ">
        <input type="radio" name="cajaradio" value="Educación" style="">
            <p class="textradio">Educación</p>
        </label>
    </div>

    <div class="imgicon images2">
        <label class="textlarge icono-empren">
        <input type="radio" name="cajaradio" value="Emprendimiento" style="">
            <p class="textradio1">Emprendimiento</p>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
 $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked'))
    //  var mensaje = $(this).val();
    {
      //alert("Seleccionaste: "+ mensaje);
        if( $('.images1').hasClass('clasehover'))
            {
                $('.images1').removeClass('clasehover');
                }
                    else{
                    $('.images1').addClass('clasehover');
                }
    }
  }); 
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Fijate de poner un código que permita hacer notar tu error, con lo que has puesto, intento replicarlo para ayudarte a buscar una solución, y no logro ver la problemática! saludos

Comment: Gracias por responder, lo que busco es que mantenga el efecto hover la imagen que clickeo, hasta el momento avance en JS:  $(function(){
  $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked'))
     var mensaje = $(this).val();
    {
      alert("Seleccionaste: "+ mensaje);
    }
  });
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si no interpreté mal tu problema, podrías hacer lo siguiente;

```js
$('.image').on('click',function(){

if( $(this).hasClass('clasehover') )
{
 $(this).removeClass('clasehover');
}
else{
$(this).addClass('clasehover');
}

});
```

```css
.image
{
 width: 300px;
 height: 300px;
 background-image: url('https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/es/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png'); 
}
.image:hover
{
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);  
}
.clasehover
{
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);  
}
```

```html
<div class="image">

</div>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-3edrmyuQ0w65f8gfBsqowzjJe2iM6n0nKciPUp8y+7E="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

El estilo cuando está la imagen en `:hover` lo definís nuevamente en otra clase también, en el ejemplo sería `clasehover`

De este modo, bastaría con detectar el evento `click` con JavaScript y agregar dicha clase al momento de hacer click en la imagen, y para ampliar un poquito el ejemplo, removerlo al volver a hacer click en esta..

Espero que sea lo que andabas buscando, saludos!

Comment: Gracias por responder nuevamente, te comento tengo 16 imágenes que los usare como botones para ser seleccionados, como ves en JS logro almacenar el icono seleccionado en una variable y lo muestro en un alert, pero al dejar de pasar el mousse pierde el efecto hover. Necesito que funciones como una input radio, que solo se seleccione 1 opción y esa opción mantenga su efecto hover, estare atento gracias.

Comment: Volví a formular la pregunta, espero este entendible, por favor nuevamente necesito su ayuda, gracias.